# VB.NET, webrequests, and proxies

Tags: vb.net, proxy

Okay, so I'm a long time lurker, first time poster. I have done quite a bit of research on this before posting, but as a self-taught programmer, I often get lost in the technical jargon.

I have a handful of VB.NET (Framework 4) applications with about 1,400 total users with all manner of network configurations. The applications are required to connect to a few publicly accessible web URLs, for which I use a WebRequest. Most users have no issues whatsoever, but a handful (usually larger companies) behind proxies do. Therefore, I'm going to allow users to specify their proxy settings (the textboxes in the code below).

This is my function so far, which returns the Request.GetResponse() as a string that I can interrogate.

```
Public Function WebRequest(ByVal Address As Uri, ByVal Timeout As Integer) As Net.WebResponse

    Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit + 1
    Net.ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 60000

    Dim Request As Net.WebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(Address)
    Request.CachePolicy = New Net.Cache.HttpRequestCachePolicy(Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore)
    Request.Timeout = Timeout
    Request.Proxy = Net.WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()

    If frmSettings.txtUsername.Text = Nothing OrElse frmSettings.txtPassword.Text = Nothing Then
        Request.UseDefaultCredentials = True
    Else
        Request.Proxy.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(frmSettings.txtUsername.Text, frmSettings.txtPassword.Text)
    End If

    Return Request.GetResponse

End Function
```

1. Are the Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit lines required?
2. Is Request.UseDefaultCredentials = True strictly necessary? I know I can specify the default network credentials as a boolean in the app.config, but my preference is not to do this. If I remove this line it runs just fine on my machine, but I don't know if it will on other users' machines.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get the system proxy and assign into your web request

```
        Dim wReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("yoururl"), HttpWebRequest)
        Dim px As IWebProxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()
        wReq.Proxy = px
        wReq.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
        wReq.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
```

Comment: I just use wReq.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials